# É possível saber a Coluna selecionada por GREATEST no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hipoteticamente, tendo 8 colunas em uma tabela X, 4 dessas colunas armazenam uma média:

```
AVG(colunaN)
```

E as outras 4 armazenam a quantidade de elementos dessa média

```
COUNT(column)
```

Em uma query estou tentando pegar a maior média dessas 4, para isso utilizo a função:

```
GREATEST(coluna1,coluna2,coluna3,coluna4) AS maior_media
```

Como eu posso fazer para identificar qual coluna foi seleciona como maior em "GREATEST" para retornar o seu

```
COUNT(colunaSelecionadaPorGreatest)
```

Que na situação acima, está armazenada em uma das outras 4 colunas.

Comment: Não seria mais prático trabalhar com linhas e não colunas? Daí bastaria um GROUP BY /MAX.

Comment: bom, na arquitetura desse meu projeto da faculdade, eu defini que é melhor eu atualizar as médias e contagens em uma tabela separada, para evitar fazer esses cálculos para cada item que vou mostrar no sistema, então ele atualiza esses dados periodicamente utilizando cronjobs.

Comment: Então faça uma gambiarra utilizando CASE / WHEN.

Answer (score 0):

Foi muito simples de resolver, encontrei o uso de variáveis no MySQL, dessa forma armazenei o resultado do "GREATEST" em uma:

```
SELECT 
    @greatest := (GREATEST(coluna1,coluna2,coluna3,coluna4)) AS greatest_average,
    CASE @greatest
         WHEN coluna1 THEN count_coluna1
         WHEN coluna2 THEN count_coluna2
         WHEN coluna3 THEN count_coluna3
         WHEN coluna4 THEN count_coluna4
    END AS greatest_counter,
    CASE @greatest
         WHEN coluna1 THEN "Qualidade"
         WHEN coluna2 THEN "Velocidade"
         WHEN coluna3 THEN "Durabilidade"
         WHEN coluna4 THEN "Quantidade"
    END AS greatest_counter_type
```

E criei dois CASES, um para armazenar o valor do contador correspondente à coluna selecionada por "GREATEST", e o outro para armazenar o tipo selecionado.